# Culture of Spanish voices

Tags: text-to-speech, voice, culture

I installed a couple of voices on my system, including some Spanish voices.
The culture of, for example American English is "en-US" and French is "fr-FR".
But for Spanish this is "es-ES_tradnl". Is there a way to change this to "es-ES"?

Thanks for your time.